# Distribution of solutions of quadratic programs

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I would like to characterize the distribution of the solutions of a convex quadratic program as the coefficient of the linear term and the rhs of the constraints vary.

I.e., if 
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& \arg \min_x \frac{1}{2} x' Q x + d' x  \\
&& s.t. \;\; A x \leq b 
\end{eqnarray}

when the problem is feasible.

And if $d$ and $b$ are independently distributed according to $d \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_d, \Sigma_d)$ and $b \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_b, \Sigma_b)$, can I say something about the distribution of $x$?

I can make progress on my problem if I can at least say something about the mean of $x$. Being able to characterize its covariance or higher moments would be even better.

I would appreciate it if someone can point me to a solution, or any relevant literature that suggests a plan of attack on this problem.

Comment: Is $Q$ positive definite? Otherwise, $x$ is not unique and thus not-well defined. If it is, have you tried sensitivity analysis on the solution?

Comment: Yes. Q is positive definite. I am not looking for a numerical solution of the problem but rather a characterization of the distribution in terms of Q, \mu_d etc.

Comment: This question is essentially asking to classify the active set of constraints as a function of $b$ and $d$. I don't think this will be easy, since there is no explicit formula for determining the active set (hence the use of Lemke's algorithm, etc, in practice).